# How to discard row based on a common column of two files using Linux cmd?

Tags: bash, unix, text-processing

file1.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
b,v,n
x,u,v
t,m,m
```

file2.csv

```
col1,col2,col3
p,m,n
a,z,i
```

`col1` acts as a primary key in both files. If any value of `col1` of `file2.csv` occurs in `file1.csv`, then this row will be discarded from `file1.csv`.

output file:

```
col1,col2,col3
b,v,n
x,u,v
t,m,m
```

**Note**: I'm interested in `Unix` based solution. please provide a solution using `sort`, `uniq`, `join`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: What is “`Linux cmd`”? Also, please post the solution you have tried. Presumably, it would include `,` as a field separator and then an associative array in Bash to store keys from the second file and then quickly test for their presence in each first field in the first file. Where did you get stuck? Please post a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command on Unix that does pretty much exactly what you want:

```
join -v1 -t, \
  <(tail +2 file1.txt | sort -k1 -t,) \
  <(tail +2 file2.txt | sort -k1 -t,)
```

For the sample files you've given, this is its output:

```
b,v,n
t,m,m
x,u,v
```

##### Command Breakdown

- `join -v1 -t,`

  - `-v1`: display rows from the 1st file that are not pairable with lines in the 2nd file via the join column (default column used for joining is 1, but it's overridable via the `-1` and `-2` options)
  - `-t,`: use comma as a field/column separator
- `<(tail +2 file1.txt | sort -k1 -t,)`

  - `<( … )`: the `join` command expects file names as arguments, so we use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to create such temporary files from the output of the nested commands
  - `tail +2 file1.txt`: skip the header line
  - `sort -k1 -t,`: the `join` command expects sorted files

    - `-t,`: use comma as a field/column separator
    - `-k1`: sort by the 1st field

Comment: @lonut could you please explain how 2 `<` work in a single cmd?

Comment: @RajanRaju sure, that's called Process Substitution (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). It works by creating temporary files and it's useful for commands that work with file names (as opposed to taking input from stdin).

Comment: @lonut I generally see one `<` at a time. Ex: `python3 main.py < input.txt`. This is the first time I'm seeing two `<`.

Comment: @RajanRaju I see, but this is a different syntax though. The parantheses are important: it's `<( ... )`, not just `< ...`. The latter only does a stdout redirect, whereas the former will output a file name in place of the entire `<( ... )` thing. The contents of that filename will be the output of the command used inside the parentheses.

Comment: @lonut if I use `join -v1 -1 1 -2 1 <(sort -k 1b,1 fixed-downloaded-metadata.tsv) <(sort -k 1b,1 bd_samples_from_aisa.tsv)`, is it redundant?

Comment: @RajanRaju it looks a bit redundant and even wrong, yes. Depends on what you're trying to solve.

Comment: That won't print the header line shown in the expected output in  the question, you need to add a `head -1 file1.csv; ` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F, '
    FNR==1 { if (NR==1) print; next }
    NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }
    !($1 in a)
' file2.csv file1.csv
col1,col2,col3
b,v,n
x,u,v
t,m,m
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **R** programming language:

```
> needle <- read.csv("/path/to/file2.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> needle
  col1 col2 col3
1    p    m    n
2    a    z    i
> 
> haystack <- read.csv("/path/to/file1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> haystack
  col1 col2 col3
1    a    b    c
2    b    v    n
3    x    u    v
4    t    m    m
> 
> haystack[!(haystack$col1 %in% needle$col1), ]
  col1 col2 col3
2    b    v    n
3    x    u    v
4    t    m    m
>
```

The above code should be pretty self-explanatory. For two-dimensional data in R, indexing is accomplished with comma-separated subscripts. As an example, for the dataframe `csv_data[i,j]` the `i`-indexing_value represents rows while the `j`-indexing_value represents columns.

[Indexing in `R` starts from number `1`, not `0`. Also, including the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to each of your `read.csv()` function calls may be superfluous depending on the age of your R-installation].

The last line gives the desired result, and you can read the code somewhat literally to mean: *"for all columns of the haystack dataframe find and return rows where `haystack$col1` does not contain (i.e. not `%in%`) `needle$col1` values".*

https://www.r-project.org/
https://cran.r-project.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
    ~$ raku -e ' \
    my @needle   = "/path/to/file2.csv".IO.lines.skip(1).map: *.split(","); \
    my @haystack = "/path/to/file1.csv".IO.lines.skip(1).map: *.split(","); \
    my @x = ([Z] @needle).[0]; my @y = @haystack.map(*.[0,3...*]); \
    .join(",").put for @haystack[@y.grep({!/@x/}, :k)]; ' file
```

Sample Output:

```
b,v,n
x,u,v
t,m,m
```

Above is a solution using the Raku programming language, a member of the Perl family of programming languages.

Briefly, files are read `line`-wise, `skip`-ping the first (header) row, and `map` is used to `split` each line on "`,`" (commas). Each `csv` file is stored as an `@`-sigiled Raku array.

After the two code lines of object creation, each array is distilled down into a single column of values. The `@needle` array is distilled down to `@x` while the `@haystack` object is distilled down to `@y`. To highlight Raku's flexibility (TIMTOWDI), two different ways of extracting the desired column are shown:

- `@x` uses the `[Z]` "zip" operator to pull off elements of each row
  such that the first elements of each row (i.e. the first column) are
  extracted.
- `@y` uses a numeric indexing sequence `[0,3...*]` to pull out the
  desired elements. Raku is smart enough to figure out the remaining
  sequence values `[0,3,6,9]`.

Finally, Raku's `grep` function is used to search for matches between `@x` and `@y`. The `:k` (key) "adverb" parameter tells Raku to return the numeric indexing position of matches, or in this case--non-matches, because `grep` uses a `!{…}` Boolean block to negate the returned match values.

**ADDENDUM:**  As @EdMorton has noted in the comments, the code above does not output column names (the first row of `file1.csv`). That's easily remedied by prepending the following line (preferably making it the line *before* `my @needle =`...  .) :

```
"/path/to/file1.csv".IO.lines[0].put;
```

https://raku.org

Comment: That won't print the header line shown in the expected output in the question.

Comment: @EdMorton Quite true. I was working from the (OP's) accepted answer, which similarly drops the header line. I'll revisit the Raku code above, but hopefully the OP will chime in to clarify which solution is actually desired:  yours (with the header) or the accepted answer (without).

Comment: @EdMorton added code (in "Addendum") to address your comment.